# Why can't I use assign operator on multiple bits?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog

For the below image, why does `assign out = a&~sel + b&sel` only output one instead of the ref solution below? Is there any way to do this problem with `assign` only?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I'm too new to comment here, but I wanted to expand on the previous answer. With one-hot mux selects, that you want to synthesize into an and-or tree, you can't use the ternary conditional operator. You have to use the replication operator. This is one thing that vhdl (I think) does better than verilog.

```
assign foo = in1 & {WIDTH{sel1}} | in0 & {WIDTH{sel0}} ;
```

If the original questioner tries something like this to replicate the select, it should work. But ternary conditional is preferred. So is if/else inside an always block.

Answer (score 1):

Could that be because the `sel` is just one bit wide?

If you wanted to use that, you'd probably have to extend the `sel` to the same width as the other inputs.

Quite frankly, I don't know why'd you want to do it that way (the (a & ~s) | (b & s) way), really. Just use the ternary operator as suggested - it really is easier to read and less cluttered. (Sure it may be confusing at first, but you'll get used to it quickly.)